# Move text programmatically from left to right

Tags: flutter

How would I make a piece of text move from left to right , disappear, and again enter(appear) from the left side of screen in Flutter ?

Comment: check `SlideTransition`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the transition you want is called a Marquee. You can achieve the following transition with the help of [any_widget_marquee](https://pub.dev/packages/any_widget_marquee), This is a custom widget and built by me. So if you have any doubts regarding this please let me know.

Comment: This looks like a great widget but after incorporating it into my project and attempting to run I see an error that `package:any_widget_marquee` doesn't support sound null safety.