# Flutter widget to display moving (marquee) text

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am hoping to display a string of text in a widget such that the text appears to automatically scroll or move from left to right, similar to what is shown in many media players ([such as OBS](https://youtu.be/oEai7s0wQsQ?t=314)). In web development, this appears to be known as a [marquee effect](https://youtu.be/FuDOuTgp8Cg?t=54).

I've looked at [animated_text_kit](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_text_kit) but it doesn't provide this scrolling animation.

I've also tried [any_widget_marquee](https://pub.dev/packages/any_widget_marquee) as described in this similar [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67437010/move-text-programmatically-from-left-to-right) but the package doesn't support sound null safety.

Can anyone provide any recommendations or describe how to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an aptly named package [marquee](https://pub.dev/packages/marquee/install) that does exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

The [ticker text](https://pub.dev/packages/ticker_text) Flutter package provides this functionality.